# How to split Abs functions into two?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have a list of functions like this:

```
    myfuncions ={ConditionalExpression[(1/2)*Abs[1 - 3*x], x >= 1 || x <= 0], 
      ConditionalExpression[Abs[1 - 2*x], x >= 1 || x <= 0], 
      ConditionalExpression[Abs[-1 + x], x >= 2 || x <= 0],
ConditionalExpression[1+x, x <= 0]};
```

For each function with Abs I want to split it into 2 funcions as follows (I take the first function as an example):

[image]

The expected output for all functions is as follows (if I don't make mistake):

```
{{ConditionalExpression[1/2 (-1 + 3 x), x >= 1], 
  ConditionalExpression[1/2 (1 - 3 x), 
   x <= 0]}, {ConditionalExpression[-1 + 2 x, x >= 1], 
  ConditionalExpression[1 - 2 x, x <= 0]}, {ConditionalExpression[
   Abs[-1 + x], x <= 0], 
  ConditionalExpression[-1 + x, x >= 2]}, {ConditionalExpression[
   1 + x, x <= 0]}}
```

[image]

Any idea to do that? I don't have problem with math but still struggle to express that into mathematica code.

Comment: Have a look at [`PiecewiseExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html).

Comment: @Roman can you explain more? I used that function before but don't know how it work here.

Comment: In second to last row of the expected output, is `ConditionalExpression[Abs[-1 + x], x <= 0]` correct?  And shouldn't `ConditionalExpression[Abs[-1 + x], x >= 2 || x <= 0]` yield a list with the `x>= 2` condition first, then the `x<=0` condition`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a function that expands the `Abs` function and simplifies the conditional expression

```
Clear[absExpand]
absExpand[e_] := With[{arg = FirstCase[e, Abs[y_] :> y, Null, ∞]},
  Simplify[e, #] & /@ {arg < 0, arg >= 0}]

expr = ConditionalExpression[(1/2)*Abs[1 - 3*x], x >= 1 || x <= 0];
absExpand[expr]
    
   (*   {ConditionalExpression[1/2 (-1 + 3 x), x >= 1], 
         ConditionalExpression[1/2 (1 - 3 x), x <= 0]}   *)
```

You may have to use `absExpand[expr]//InputForm` to see exactly the output shown above.

Comment: Thanks, would it be okay to use `e` here instead of `expr`?
It tried and it worked but I'm not sure if there is some hidden problems.
`FirstCase[e, Abs[y_] :> y, Null, \[Infinity]]`

Comment: @hana Good catch!  That's definitely a mistake that I must have introduced in a last-minute edit.  I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 4):

The following deals with an expression that has one or more `Abs` functions, being treated as `RealAbs`. It's probably more robust to replace `Abs -> RealAbs`, but in the OP's examples, the inequalities imply to `PiecewiseExpand` that `Abs` may be treated as the real absolute value (or more precisely, the complex absolute value restricted to a real argument).

```
(* ConditionalExpression to Piecewise *)
ceToPWRule = ConditionalExpression[e_, c_] :> 
   PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{e, c}}, Inactive@Undefined]];
(* Split Piecewise cases into list of ConditionExpressions *)
splitPiecewiseRule = Verbatim[Piecewise][ff_, def_] :>
   (Piecewise[{#}, Undefined] & /@ ff);
```

First example (output shown both in `StandardForm` and `InputForm`):

```
Replace[First@myfuncions, 
 f_ :> (PiecewiseExpand[f /. ceToPWRule] /. splitPiecewiseRule)]
```

> [image]

All the OP's function (the last has only one case):

```
Activate[
 Replace[myfuncions, 
  f_ :> (PiecewiseExpand[f /. ceToPWRule] /. splitPiecewiseRule), 1],
 Undefined]
```

> [image]

Example with two `Abs[]`:

```
Activate[
  Replace[
   ConditionalExpression[Abs[x - 7], x (10 - x) >= 0] + myfuncions, 
   f_ :> (PiecewiseExpand[f /. ceToPWRule] /. splitPiecewiseRule), 
   1],
  Undefined] // Simplify
```

> [image]

Comment: This is great too. I didn't know `RealAbs` and `Activate` exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
myfuncions = {ConditionalExpression[(1/2)*Abs[1 - 3*x], x >= 1 || x <= 0],
              ConditionalExpression[Abs[1 - 2*x], x >= 1 || x <= 0],
              ConditionalExpression[Abs[-1 + x], x >= 2 || x <= 0],
              ConditionalExpression[1 + x, x <= 0]};

PiecewiseExpand /@ myfuncions
```

$$
\left\{\fbox{$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} (1-3 x) & x\leq \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{2} (3 x-1) & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\text{ if }x\geq 1\lor x\leq 0$},\fbox{$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1-2 x & x\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
 2 x-1 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\text{ if }x\geq 1\lor x\leq 0$},\fbox{$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1-x & x<1 \\
 x-1 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\text{ if }x\geq 2\lor x\leq 0$},\fbox{$x+1\text{ if }x\leq 0$}\right\}
$$

I don't know how to go further with [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html). However, with [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) we can go all the way. I've used [`Indeterminate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indeterminate.html) to mark values outside of the condition; but you can use anything else like [`Missing[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html), [`$Failed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Failed.html), etc.:

```
myfunctions = {Piecewise[{{(1/2)*Abs[1 - 3*x], x >= 1 || x <= 0}}, Indeterminate],
               Piecewise[{{Abs[1 - 2*x], x >= 1 || x <= 0}}, Indeterminate],
               Piecewise[{{Abs[-1 + x], x >= 2 || x <= 0}}, Indeterminate],
               Piecewise[{{1 + x, x <= 0}}, Indeterminate]};

PiecewiseExpand /@ myfunctions
```

$$
\{
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} (1-3 x) & x\leq 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} (3 x-1) & x\geq 1 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
\end{array}
\right.
,\\
 \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 1-2 x & x\leq 0 \\
 2 x-1 & x\geq 1 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
\end{array}
\right.
,\\
 \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 1-x & x\leq 0 \\
 x-1 & x\geq 2 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
\end{array}
\right.
,\\
 \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 x+1 & x\leq 0 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
\end{array}
\right.
\}
$$

Comment: I see, I think you misunderstood my question. The output is not of the `expected output` as I mentioned above.

Comment: Please see update

Comment: I admit it's hard to understand what is being sought. I didn't get it until I saw LouisB's answer.  The OP gives four functions and an output of only two, and a mysterious combining that include the disjunction of a boolean inequality and a scalar-value conditional expression -- hard to understand. I think what the OP wants is another step: To split each of the `Piecewise` functions you obtained into a `ConditionalExpression` for each case (except `Indeterminate`).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think my comment on how to obtain the result in human way was confusing. I picked one function as an example and showed the process of obtaning the result as a human.

Comment: @hana It seems better now. The combining of the inequality and `ConditionalExpression` was confusing to me. Further, it might be nicer, since you give four input functions, to also give the four outputs. It would let me confirm my understanding of the description of the human way.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

myfuncions = {ConditionalExpression[(1/2)*Abs[1 - 3*x], 
    x >= 1 || x <= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[Abs[1 - 2*x], x >= 1 || x <= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[Abs[-1 + x], x >= 2 || x <= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[1 + x, x <= 0]};

myfuncions /. 
 ConditionalExpression[expr_, 
   Or[a_, 
    b_]] :>
  (ConditionalExpression[Simplify[expr, #], #] & /@ {a, b})

(* {{ConditionalExpression[1/2 (-1 + 3 x), x >= 1], 
  ConditionalExpression[1/2 (1 - 3 x), 
   x <= 0]}, {ConditionalExpression[-1 + 2 x, x >= 1], 
  ConditionalExpression[1 - 2 x, 
   x <= 0]}, {ConditionalExpression[-1 + x, x >= 2], 
  ConditionalExpression[Abs[-1 + x], x <= 0]}, 
 ConditionalExpression[1 + x, x <= 0]} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Refine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html), and fixing the expected output to not have an `Abs` and be in an order consistent with the rest of the output.

```
condAbsExpand[expr_?(StringContainsQ["Abs"]@*ToString)] := ConditionalExpression[Refine[expr[[1]], #], #] & /@ List @@ expr[[2]]
condAbsExpand[expr_] := Identity@expr

condAbsExpand@ConditionalExpression[(1/2)*Abs[1 - 3*x], x >= 1 || x <= 0]
condAbsExpand/@ myfuncions - expected // Simplify
```

> {ConditionalExpression[1/2 (-1 + 3 x), x >= 1], ConditionalExpression[1/2 (1 - 3 x), x <= 0]}

> {{ConditionalExpression[0, x >= 1], ConditionalExpression[0, x <= 0]}, {ConditionalExpression[0, x >= 1], ConditionalExpression[0, x <= 0]}, {ConditionalExpression[0, x >= 2], ConditionalExpression[0, x <= 0]}, ConditionalExpression[0, x <= 0]}}